# Series question with unknown limit

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am doing an A Level Core 2 paper and the last question caught me out. The question is:

$$\sum_1^{2N} (3r+5) - \sum_1^N (3r+5) = 1256$$

```
Find N.
```

How can I do this? I've worked out so far that the LHS can be written as $\sum_N^{2N} 3r+5$ but I can't figure out where to go from there. How do I find N?

Comment: You should use the formula $\sum_{n=1}^N n = \frac{N(N+1)}2$.

Comment: Is there parentheses that we can see? Is it $\;\sum (3r+5)\;$ , or else $\;\sum 3r\;\;+5\;$ ?

Comment: @Timbuc sorry, edited. It's the first one, your answer still stands ;)

Comment: The LHS is clearly a strictly increasing function of $N$, so if you're allowed to use a calculator, you could simply try a few values. Something like a binary search ought to yield the correct value quickly.

Comment: @DavidZhang I would have tried a numerical method only the question was worth 5 marks and explicitly said calculate, so I don't think a trial and error method would have scored me the marks

Comment: @imulsion I see. If, as you say, you aren't supposed to use the formula for the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers, I don't think there's really any other approach.

Comment: @DavidZhang Ok, thanks for your help. I'll use the natural numbers formula method - I'm sure my teacher won't mind...

Comment: @imulsion Are you sure that formula is not to be used? I do recall learning how to sum arithmetic sequences in closed form in my high school algebra classes (though I understand things may be different outside the US).

Comment: @DavidZhang As I understand it you do much more algebra in the US than we do in the UK. I don't ever remember learning that formula outside of FP1 (which is a module only further maths students do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$$\sum_{n=1}^N3n=3\sum_{n=1}^Nn=3\frac{N(N+1)}2$$

Since you actually have, say

$$\sum_{r=1}^N (3r+5)=3\sum_{r=1}^Nr+\sum_{r=1}^N5=3\frac{N(N+1)}2+5N$$

Proof of the first sum above: we do the same sum in two ways

$$\begin{align}&S=1&+&2&+\ldots+&(N-1)&+&N\\
&S=N&+&(N-1)&+\ldots+&2&+&1\end{align}$$

Sum now both lines above:

$$2S=\overbrace{(N+1)+(N+1)+\ldots+(N+1)}^{n\;\text{ times}}=N(N+1)$$

and now you can deduce the sum of the first $\;n\;$ consecutive natural numbers.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about that expansion. The only thing is that we don't do series expansions of $n$, $n^2$ etc until further pure 1 (so students doing this paper would most likely not know those expansions). Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "series expansion of $\;n\,,\,n^2\;$..." and etc. What we've used above is the sum of the first $\;n\;$ *consecutive* natural numbers, and you must use that **twice** (for both sums), and you don't need sum of squares or stuff.

Comment: What I mean is students doing the C2 paper don't know the formula for the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers. I only know it because I'm doing further maths and we learn about it on FP1, so I was wondering if there was another method. If not, don't worry, I can still use your answer :)

Comment: @imulsion See my edits to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

As $3(n+1)+5-[3n+5]=3$ which is the common difference,

We need $\sum_{n=N+1}^{2N}(3n+5)$

Now $\sum_{r=c}^d[a+rD]=\dfrac{d-c+1}2\left[2\{a+cD\}+(d-c)D\right]$